# How to allow 100 char in a textbox whose mode is multiple?

Tags: asp.net

In my form I used textbox whose mode is multiple.I want to allow only 100 character (including number,special character and char).Maxlength will not work with textbox.What will be my Regular Expression?

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tb" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" ></asp:TextBox>

//Regular Expression validator
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" 
runat="server" ControlToValidate="tb" 
ErrorMessage="Please enter maximum 100 charachters."
SetFocusOnError="true" ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z.]{0,100}$">
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

This include character only.I want number,spl char or any but count should not greater than 100.How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Try this ---> .{1,100} it will limit the value to any char 1 to 100 times. i.e. use ^.{1,100}$.... so you can set min and max char allowed by this way..

if you also want to allow only some special characters then use this `ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z0-9'@&#.\s]{1,100}$"`

Comment: Thanks jitendra,for ur help.I got solution.I want to restrict only number of character.Max character is 100.So my expression is like this.ValidationExpression="^[\s\S]{0,100}$"

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function CheckLength(textBox, maxLength) {
          if (textBox.value.length > maxLength) {
               alert("Max characters allowed are " + maxLength);
               textBox.value = textBox.value.substr(0, maxLength);
          }
     }
</script>

<asp:TextBox ID="txtData" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" 
onKeyUp="javascript:CheckLength(this, 100);"onChange="javascript:CheckLength(this, 100);" />
```

Hope this will work for you...

Cheers..